# Text Align DocuSign Custom Fields/Tags

Tags: docusignapi

I'm building my custom template in DocuSign. I can't seem to find a way to align the text (left, right, center) in the web-based user interface nor through the XML for a template.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not currently have a text align parameter (in the web app or in the API).

You can use the web app to align the tab locations (so they all appear on the same x or y axis).

Answer (score 0):

You could write an API script that does the same, sets the x or y position on all tags in a template.  Oh, unless OP meant text alignment **within** a tag..... If so, I don't think that's possible in anyway.  Seems text justifies left, and calculated (formula) numbers justify right.....